# Android java.io.FileNotFoundException image open failed: ENOENT from internal storage

Tags: java, android, image, file, multipart

Hello I am working with android . I want to save multiple captured images in a folder(programmatically created in internal storage of the device) and read this file from the folder and send to server as multipart form. I used the below code for attaching images to multipart ,

```
for(int i=0;i<Captured_imagePath.size();i++) {
   try {
      final File file2 = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/" + Captured_imagePath.get(i));

      final FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file2);
      entityBuilder.addPart(file2.getName(), fileBody);
      entityBuilder.setBoundary(boundary);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Except:: " + e.toString());
   }
}
```

When I use only one image in this loop it works fine. When more than one images, it cause the following exception

```
 8594-9144/? W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/MyFolder/ 20160123_121858.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-23 12:19:09.525    8594-9144/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-23 12:19:09.525    8594-9144/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-23 12:19:09.525    8594-9144/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-23 12:19:09.525    8594-9144/? W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).
```

I added permissions in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

my complete multpart uploading method is

```
   public String uploadMultipart(String url,String json ,ArrayList<String> imagePath,ArrayList<String> Captured_imagePath) {
        String result="";
        File  file=null;
        String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();



        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            entityBuilder.addTextBody("json", json);
            entityBuilder.setBoundary(boundary);
            if(imagePath.size()!=0)
            {
                file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/" + imagePath.get(0));

                entityBuilder.addBinaryBody(file.getName(), file,  ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), imagePath.get(0));

                entityBuilder.setBoundary(boundary);
            }

            if(Captured_imagePath.size()!=0)
            {

                for(int i=0;i<Captured_imagePath.size();i++)
                {

                    try {


                        final File file2 = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/" + Captured_imagePath.get(i));



                        final FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file2);
                        entityBuilder.addPart(file2.getName(), fileBody);
                        entityBuilder.setBoundary(boundary);

                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Except:: " + e.toString());
                    }

                }


            }


            HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            entity.writeTo(bytes);
            String content = bytes.toString();

        //    Log.i(TAG,"sending data"+content);
          //  writeToFile("shanu",content);

            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.i(TAG2, result);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString();
```

I had searched for this file in my folder manually and it exist in the same folder.Then why I got this file not found exception ? How can I resolve this issue? please help.

Comment: How are you doing the looping of loading more than one image? Need he code to verify

Comment: There seems to be a space after `MyFolder/` i.e /storage/sdcard0/MyFolder/<space>20160123_121858.jpg. this is causing the problem.

Comment: @Harry: here Captured_imagePath is arrayList of image names and looping upto arraylist size and attach each item to entityBuilder inside the loop. IS it a wrong approach ??

Comment: can you post the whole code? If the network connection is done in a loop and if you have not provided a wait mechanism to complete once image upload and proceeding with next may give error...

Comment: @Harry: please check  my new edits

Comment: @AlimParkar: thanks a lot man..finally I found the error after a week of research and debugging . Once again thanks ,U saved a lot of time :)

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra white space in your path.

Try with this

```
file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyFolder/" + imagePath.get(0).toString().trim());
```